# Convert RandomState to Generator in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, random, generator

The other day I saw that `numpy.random.RandomState` is considered legacy and should be replaced with `numpy.random._generator.Generator` instances obtained through `numpy.random.default_rng(seed)`.
Now I want to update my package that uses `RandomState` to use `Generator` instead. I have a helper function that can receive a variety of input types and returns an RNG (already updated to use `Generator`):

```py
import numpy as np
from hashlib import md5

def get_random_state(state=None):
    if isinstance(state, np.random._generator.Generator):
        return state
    if isinstance(state, np.random.RandomState):
        raise TypeError('RandomState instances are no longer supported!')
    if state is None:
        return np.random.default_rng()
    try:
        seed = int(state)
    except ValueError:
        # use hash digest when seed is a (non-numerical) string
        seed = int(md5(state.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(), 16) & 0xffffffff
    return np.random.default_rng(seed)
```

This way, if the method gets a `RandomState` object it just raises a type error.
Now I have used the package in many projects where I give this method a `RandomState` instance, and I wonder if there is a way to make this code backwards-compatible so that you can just give it a `RandomState` instance and have it converted to a `Generator`. The most straightforward way that comes to mind would be this:

```py
    seed = state.randint(1<<32)
    return np.random.default_rng(seed)
```

But I wonder if it is possible to use the internal state of the legacy object to create a `Generator`?

Comment: Are you working with the assumption that your legacy states are for a PCG64 generator and not a MT19937? Otherwise conversion will not be always possible

Comment: See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/performance.html